# How to assign Azure App Services within a single App Service plan to different subnets within a virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-plans

Within a given Azure "pay-as-you-go" subscription, I currently have a single App Service Plan which includes multiple App Services;  let's call them **App Service 1**, **App Service 2**, and **App Service 3**.

I have setup a single Azure Virtual Network which includes two subnets - let's call them **Subnet A** and **Subnet B**.

I am trying to assign **App Service 1** and **App Service 2** to **Subnet A** via the Azure Portal, ie:

[image]

This works perfectly.

I then hop over to **App Service 3** and attempt to assign it to **Subnet B** within that same virtual network;  when I attempt to do so, I get the following error:

[image]

("VNet configuration failed.: Adding this VNET would exceed the App Service Plan VNET limit of 1.")

I'm at a loss here as I only have a single VNET (with multiple sub-nets);  is what I'm trying to do not possible, and the error message really should be informing me that all app services within a given app service plan can only be associated with a single sub-net?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8b51183-d94b-48c9-9b6c-e6a4dbec9919/vnet-integration-limit-of-1?forum=azureappconfiguration The last comment by SamaraSoucy-MSFT seems to suggest there is one subnet per app service plan limit. The comment by Goofoff suggests a workaround. hope that helps

Comment: That wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but after reading up more about the relationship between an App Service Plan and contained App Services, it now makes much more sense as to why a given App Service Plan can only support a single VNET / subnet.  Your link helped me find additional information on this subject - many thanks!

Comment: Glad you found the link helpful. Cheers!

Comment: it seems the workaround doesn't work anymore